# All possible combinations out of 2 Arrays

Tags: java, c#, nested-loops

I have 2 Arrays:

```
  A {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} 
  B {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

I want to make the user be able to input a x number and then the program should print out all possible multiplications that `= x`.
the multiplication that `= x` should be made of 2 numbers 1 of array A and the other number from array B. The numbers cannot be the same.

I've been searching and the only thing I think could work is a nested loop.
I am doing this little project in C# but I kindly don't care if it's in Java I understand also Java.
Thanks in advance for the help.

```
int num_user;
        int[] x = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, };
        int[] y = new int[9];
        Console.WriteLine("Hello please input the number  you think could be the solution :) ");
        num_user = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int a = 0; a < x.Length; a++ )
            for (int b = 0; b < y.Length; b++)
                if num_user == a*b //and here is where I get lost
```

Comment: _I am doing this little project in C#_ Where is your code?

Comment: Yes.  A nested loop would work.  Why don't you try to write one?  (If you are learning to program, you will learn more / better if you write the code yourself.  Or at least *try* ...)

Comment: I think showing the nested loop approach and some example would explain the problem much better as it is not clear

Comment: Are the arrays always the numbers 0 through 9, or is the program required to work also if they are something else?

Comment: Am I understanding correctly? “The numbers cannot be the same.” So for x = 25, the program should print nothing at all? 5 * 5 = 25, but 5 is the same as 5.

Comment: I apologise may be I should have pasted what I've done.  just standby I am trying to make this work

Comment: Regarding the code in your question. it seems to me that you should study the syntax of an `if` statement in C#, and you should be able to get through. A detail, array `x` has length 10 and array `y` has length 9, wonder if the difference is on purpose?

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] a = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int[] b = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

int target = 5; //The number you want the 2 numbers to multiply to

var query =
    from x in a
    from y in b
    where y != x && x * y == target
    select new { x, y };

foreach (var pair in query) Console.WriteLine(pair);
```

Comment: *Cartesian Join* - `from x in a from y in b` - is the thing which should be used with *care*. What if initial arrays are large, say, `a =  Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).ToArray();` and `b =  Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).ToArray()`?

Comment: Dennis_E thanks for your help it's simple and I get it!

Answer (score 0):

a simple nested loop would work for this

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
    {
        if (x != y && x*y == your_number) System.out.format("%d * %d = %d\n",x,y,your_number);
    }
}
```

code not tested, but sth like this should work.
you'll have to implement the arrays for yourself :)

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = string.Empty;
        int output = 0;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number: ");
            input = /* Console.ReadLine(); */ "8";
        } while (!int.TryParse(input, out output));
        int[] first = new int[] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        int[] second = new int[] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        var list = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < first.Length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < second.Length; j++)
                if (first[i] * second[j] == output)
                    list.Add(first[i] + " x " + second[j] + " = " + output);
        foreach (var str in list) {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }
}
```

See a live demonstration [here](http://ideone.com/ZuhACv)

This code accepts user input *(set to "8" for testing purposes)* and will loop through the first array items and then loop through the second array.A multiplication is done for each item in the first by each item in the second using this nested loop logic.
Hope this helped you in some way.

Comment: Thanks for your help it's very helpful but a bit too much difficult for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the double loop, as a couple of the other answers do.

In case you want to avoid a double loop (for some particular reason), it can be done without it. In Java:

```
    int[] a = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    // not using b

    int x = 8;

    for (int firstFactor : a) {
        if (firstFactor != 0 && x % firstFactor == 0) {
            int secondFactor = x / firstFactor;
            if (0 <= secondFactor && secondFactor <= 9 && secondFactor != firstFactor) {
                System.out.println("" + firstFactor + " * " + secondFactor);
            }
        }
    }
```

The code above does not work for `x` equal to 0, you would have to treat this case specially (which you don’t have to in the double loop approach). For `x` equal to 8 the code prints:

```
1 * 8
2 * 4
4 * 2
8 * 1
```

Comment: Ole the user enters a number and the program is suposed to find two numbers one of each array: "a" and "b". a*b=user input. a and b cannot be the same number. //can someone help me, allways when I press enter it submits the comment but I just want to make a space!

Comment: Ah, @oscar6662, you’ve edited the question. Thanks for doing that, I believe it’s getting clearer. If the problem is C# console input, I’m probably not the right one to help, though. Will check any upcoming edits.

Comment: BTW I tested and read your code but I didn't get what ":" does                     for (int firstFactor : a) {

Comment: Ah, that’s the Java so-called enhanced for loop. It iterates through the array `a` and assigns each element of the array to `firstFactor` in turn. Pretty much like the `foreach` loop in C#, I believe.

Comment: Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html, the example near the bottom of the page.

Comment: oh that's maybe because I didnt find it I was searching ":" in C#.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using *Linq* while avoiding *Cartesian Join* (what if `A` and `B` are large?):

```
  int[] A = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
  int[] B = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

  int goal = 10;

  var result = A
    .Where(a => a != 0 && goal % a == 0) // a from A is divider of the goal 
    .Where(goal / a != a)                // a and b can't be the same 
    .Where(a => B.Contains(goal / a))    // b is in B
    .OrderBy(a => a)                     // let be nice
    .Select(a => string.Format("{0} {1}", a, goal / a));
```

Test

```
  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome

```
  2 5
  5 2
```

Stress test:

```
  int[] A = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).ToArray();
  int[] B = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).ToArray();

  int goal = 2016;
```

will return within milliseconds

```
1 2016
2 1008
3 672
4 504
6 336
7 288
8 252
9 224
... 
504 4
672 3
1008 2
2016 1
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your help! and time!